# How to send data from android to bind with the model object in Spring mvc

Tags: android, spring-mvc

This is register.jsp files portion no problem with it. How to send data from android mobile application or can i do any changes in the controller, please assist. Thank you for your help.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String createNewUser(Model model, @ModelAttribute(value = "user") User user,
      BindingResult errors, HttpServletRequest request) {
      // this is working properly for both mobile and laptop(directly website) links
      user.getUsername()
        // here i am getting "NullPointerException" because email is binded to user and not to model not to UserMetaData Model in case of android, it is working fine laptop as in html file we are providing path="userMetaData.email"
        //So what to do send it in same way from android application too.
      user.getUserMetadata().getEmail();

      return "true";
    }
```

> Below is my Pojo classes

**User.java**

```
Public class User {
      private String username;

      @
      Column(name = "USERNAME", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 80)
      public String getUsername() {
        return this.userName;
      }

      public void setUsername(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
      }
    }
```

**UserMetadata.java**

```
public class UserMetadata {
      private String email;

      @
      Column(name = "EMAIL", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 40)
      public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
      }
    }
```

> Below is my JSP page:-

```
<label>Username</label>
    <form:input path="username" class="form-control input-sm bounceIn animation-delay2" placeholder="User Name" />
    </div>
    <!-- /form-group -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Password</label>
      <form:password path="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control input-sm bounceIn animation-delay3" />
    </div>
    <!-- /form-group -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Confirm Password</label>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm password" id='confirmpass' name='confirmpass' class="form-control input-sm bounceIn animation-delay4">
    </div>
    <!-- /form-group -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Email Address</label>
      <form:input path="userMetadata.email" id='email' placeholder="Email address" class="form-control input-sm bounceIn animation-delay5" />
    </div>
    <!-- /form-group -->
```

Please provide you answer with example, actually the data is to be saved in the database so i cannot change the model, I have to bind the data in such a way that i should use the model in the same way as it is designed i can only make changes in the android code or controller code of spring.